# Find name of specific member (structure)

Tags: .net, vb.net, types, structure

I have the following structure :

```
   Public Structure sTableLookup
        Public id As Long
        Public code As String
        Public description As String
        Public descriptionang As String
    End Structure
```

And then I have this array of type sTableLookup :

```
 Public arrData() As sTableLookup
```

After I fill the array with data, I would like to be able to "extract" the name of the member when looping the data:

```
For Each oRow As sTableLookup In arrData
    'find a way of returning the string "code" from this:
    oRow.code
    'or "description" from this:
    oRow.description
Next
```

Can I use Reflection to to this?

Thanks!

Comment: They *all* have a "code" and "description" field so why do you have to loop?  Hard to understand what you are really after

Comment: Are you trying to do a reverse lookup?  Find whether "code" or "description" contains a certain value?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to do, but with the current version of Visual Basic (in VS 2015), you can use NameOf to return the name of an element. For example

```
Dim codeName As String = NameOf(oRow.code) 'codeName will be "code"
```